# Error: Invalid instruction 'versionCode', valid instructions are : REMOVE,REPLACE,STRICT

Tags: android-studio

[image]

```
Error: Invalid instruction 'versionCode', valid instructions are : REMOVE,REPLACE,STRICT
```

Comment: You should show your code, configuration, and information on what you were doing when they error occurred, or how it was caused.

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: Perhaps you could show the file where you set this value, or really anything about what you're doing -- is this for a specific platform, application, instruction set, etc.?